# Create contour line from point table in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, vector, contour

I have a point table containing values ranging from 0 to 100 and I would like to draw a contour line for the value 70. (See image below)

I know how to create contour lines in QGIS for raster data but now I would like to do it with vector data (my point table) using PostGIS so that it can be integrated in a python script.

Any idea on how to start?

EDIT:
This question is different from [Generating contour lines and filled contours from points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42020/generating-contour-lines-and-filled-contours-from-points) as it doesn't involve raster data (neither in the input nor in the output)

[image]

Comment: this is a very complex clustering problem, and there isn't nearly enough information (afaik) to tackle it. For instance, how do you know both of those 70s aren't islands?

Comment: If you have a Python script that does contouring, you can create a fucntion in Postgis using [pythonu extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-funcs.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is something like [`gdal_contour`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html).

```
gdal_contour: Builds vector contour lines from a raster elevation model.


Usage: gdal_contour [-b <band>] [-a <attribute_name>] [-3d] [-inodata]
                    [-snodata n] [-i <interval>]
                    [-f <formatname>] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...] [[-lco NAME=VALUE] ...]
                    [-off <offset>] [-fl <level> <level>...]
                    [-nln <outlayername>]
                    <src_filename> <dst_filename>
```

But PostGIS doesn't seem to [implement anything like that from GDAL](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=contour&type=).

GDAL expects a input raster elevation model (DEM). PostGIS has a few [DEM functions](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html#Raster_Processing_DEM) but I don't believe they'll help you here.

Answer (score 1):

To create contour in PostGIS I usually use [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_ConvexHull.html) or [ST_ConcaveHull](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_ConcaveHull.html)

Usage of it is simple as that:

```
SELECT
  st_convexhull(st_collect(geom)),
               pointsId
             FROM point_table 
             GROUP BY pointId;
```

But to create polygon like at your picture is not really easy.

You can try some other functions using this [cheatsheet](http://www.postgis.us/downloads/postgis20_cheatsheet.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something very similar, I found an item at
[fast contour lines using plain postgis[1](https://abelvm.github.io/sql/contour/). it creates a contour map from your list of points. I get the impression it expects rectangle input.

My problem with this solution was the calling method, it uses array of data, a concept which is outside of most sql grammers.

My data weather point data, where  geom the point location, speed a scalar value denoting the current wind speed and reading_time the value data was collected.

My calling code is

```
drop table foo;
create table foo(
    id serial,
    geom geometry ,
    break numeric 

);
insert into foo (geom,break )  
select 
    (contour_lines(  array_agg(geom),array_agg(speed::numeric), 
    ARRAY[ 0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5,5.0,5.5,6.0,6.5,7.0,7.5,8.0,8.5,9.0,9.5,10.0,10.5,11.0,11.5,12.0,12.5,13.0,13.5,14.0,14.5,15.0,15.5,16.0,16.5] )).geom ,  
    (contour_lines(  array_agg(geom),array_agg(speed::numeric), 
    ARRAY[ 0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5,5.0,5.5,6.0,6.5,7.0,7.5,8.0,8.5,9.0,9.5,10.0,10.5,11.0,11.5,12.0,12.5,13.0,13.5,14.0,14.5,15.0,15.5,16.0,16.5] )).break
from windproc where reading_time='2018-08-28 07:00:00+01'  and geom is not null and speed is not null;
```

Where array_agg creates an array of the object supply as an argument.  The array construct creates a list of step/break values which is used a banding values for the generated contour lines.

The code for contour_lines is provided by the link. it expects a numeric value for scalar value (in my case speed) hence the cast.

The reason there is what appears to be a double called to contour_lines is that you need to get the break and geom answers provide by contour_lines function, but since array_agg is an aggrate function it can only appear in some parts of sql construct.

The result from this will give you a table called foo with the desired information in the geom column